# iPhone 6 Plus resolution: make use of the downscaling support or add @3x images

Tags: ios, iphone, image

My question is mainly related to quality and performance of using the downscaling support of the iOS which uses the @2x resolution images for iPhone 6 plus if the @3x is not available or if it is better to generate the @3x set of images and add it to the project. 
The downscaling affects the performance of the app?
The quality of the raster downscaled images is the same as the ones made using Photoshop for example? (I'm not talking about vector images).

I ask this so I can decide if it would be better to invest time in scaling the @2x raster images and add the @3x ones to the project (downside: time invested in scaling and the app have a bigger size).

Thank you!

Comment: Typically having 3x vs 2x images will not significantly affect performance.  If you have very large images or a great number of images, then it might be an issue.  It will probably look better on an iPhone 6+ if you have 3x images but if you think the 2x images look fine, that is up to you.